# Facebook,Graph API

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

From where I can start For interaction with Facebook like post Image on wall, get friend list, post image on friend wall etc. I already read basics from [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/) (Facebook GuideLines). Any good resources for learn Graph API and latest API documentation or tutorial?

thanks

Comment: download the sample app https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/tree/master/sample/Hackbook

Comment: @janusfidel thanks. good sample app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/